# Read data from File in magento2 InstallData.php

Tags: magento2, installdata

I have my InstallData but i want to read a file in SQL/CSV format in magento 2

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
{
    $setup->startSetup();

    $tableName = $setup->getTable('custom_table');

        $data = [
            [
                //Read file in sql/CSV format.
            ],

        ];

        $setup
            ->getConnection()
            ->insertMultiple($tableName, $data);

    $setup->endSetup();
}
```

How do i go about this in magento2...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `file_get_contents`.

If we suppose that your file is in a directory 'Files' in your module called Test :

`$data = file_get_contents($this->directoryList->getModuleDir('','Project_Test').'/Files/file.csv');`

where `directoryList` is Magento\Framework\Module\Dir\Reader;